# Problem detecting empty REQUEST_URI with Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am running Apache witha redirect rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://2nd-domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

This successfully redirects http://1st-domain.com to http://2nd-domain.com
However, when the REQUEST_URI is empty, I want to redirect to a third domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://3rd-domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

But this does not work and instead redirects to 2nd-domain.com

My rules are ordered like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://3rd-domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://2nd-domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

1. Empty REQUEST_URI:  http:/1st-domain.com
2. Non-empty REQUEST_URI:  http://1st-domain.com/something

The first rule should direct an empty request_uri to 3rd-domain.com, the second rule should direct the non-empty request_uri to 2nd-domain.com

**USEFUL TIDBIT**
You can turn on mod_rewrite debug with this snippet:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteLog "/home/domain.com/logs/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
</IfModule>
```

Very useful debug option I hadn't known.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684931/

Comment: *REQUEST\_URI* is never empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^$ http://3rd-domain.com [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://2nd-domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Hope it helps!

Note: REQUEST_URI is slightly different between httpd.conf and .htaccess, it starts with an extra backslash in httpd.conf. This means that in httpd.conf the first rewrite rule should be `^\/$`, not just `^$`.

Comment: thanks for trying, but the second rule picks up both requests an empty and non-empty request_uri. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok I worked it out, but your answer was very close. A: Apache never returns an empty request_uri, an empty request comes through as '/' so I just changed the first rewrite rule to ^\/$ and it works!

Comment: @crunchyt: Your rewrite rules are in httpd.conf, correct? I tested mine in .htaccess. REQUEST_URI is slightly different between httpd.conf and .htaccess, it starts with an extra backslash in httpd.conf. Glad you have figure it out! :)

Comment: Exactly, me too I had to use ^\/$, because I've put the rule in httpd.conf. It works like a charm, thank you all very much!

Comment: doesn't work for me, I don't think slash need escape.

Comment: The `REQUEST_URI` server variable _always_ has a slash prefix, regardless of where it is used. But it's not the `REQUEST_URI` server variable that is being used here; it's the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ - it is this URL-path that differs between _server_ and _directory_ (ie. `.htaccess`) context.

Answer (score 13):

I am using the following to catch empty REQUEST_URL:

`RewriteEngine on`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  "^/$"`

`RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/my/another/url`

Comment: how to check if its NOT empty?

Comment: @harrrrrrry You can prefix the regex with `!` to _negate_ it. eg. `!^/$`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://2nd-domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://3rd-domain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?1st-domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule .* http://3rd-domain.com/ [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule .* http://2nd-domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

whitout the quotes on the empty validation

Answer (score 0):

Your rules redirects request with empty `QUERY_STRING`.

For empty request_uri, you can use

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://3rd-domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://2nd-domain.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The first rule will first match `<empty>`, then tests for `<non-empty or empty>` (which can't be `<empty>` now since we've processed it before)

Answer (score 0):

On multisites such redirection works for me for empty requests :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1st-domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/$"
RewriteRule ^$ http://3rd-domain.com/ [R=permanent,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If request is empty apache 'redirects' to index.html so -RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index-  might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the options stated on this page, all I wanted was to check if the REQUEST_URI is empty (or in this particular case, a `/`):

```
# Check of the request uri is just 1 char long (checking for a slash was harder):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.$
```

Comment: "checking for a slash was harder"? `^/$`

Comment: Apart from this being an older answer, I believe there was a reason that that wasn't an option. Cant think of it though