# How to check if REQUEST_URI is not empty in apache RewriteCond httpd.conf?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In [Problem detecting empty REQUEST_URI with Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684940/problem-detecting-empty-request-uri-with-apache-mod-rewrite) , its mentioned we can use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.$
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/$"
```

I need to check if its not empty, then redirect it to an empty one(ignore all the string after HTTP_HOST).

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"^/$"
RewriteRule .*  http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]
```

but not work. It just caused an endless loop.

Also I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$` also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/$` also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^/$"` also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^\/$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

`RewriteRule ^/.+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]`

Comment: it doesn't work. when I tried http://xx.com/asdf it does redirect to http://xx.com. but then it caused an endless loop ag

Comment: A request for just your site name (xx.com) is still going to serve something. You have to set a condition to ignore that something. If you just request the site's name (xx.com), then you will be served whatever your DirectoryIndex directive is pointing to, default being /index.html. So you have to put in a preceding condition to avoid execution for that particular URI.  For example:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteRule ^/.+$ http://%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=301]

Comment: I tried to debug with `RewriteRule .*  http://test.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` to confirm what the final REQUEST_URI it is. it shows me REQUEST_URI is a single `/`. Also I tried ur approach `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index `(just match any potential index name), it doesn't work also.

Comment: That RewriteCond and RewriteRule pair should work as long as the Cond is pointing to the correct underlying URI. What happens if you comment out those Rewrites, bounce Apache and just hit your site's name again. What is displayed in the browser? Review your httpd.conf and see what the DirectoryIndex entry is pointing to.

Comment: Without those rewrites, it just shows the php correctly I configured in .htaccess(/news/test.php,). Isn't virtualhost rules' priority higher than rules in .htaccess?

Comment: sorry, I assumed this was all just in the main config. didn't realize this was in a vhost and your homepage was defined in .htaccess. That may bring more scope and precedence issues into play... or may not.  Don't know enough about the rest of your config. Given what you've explained tho, try plugging your php URI into the condition:  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/test.php   ALSO NOTE: You can always add the following lines to enable rewrite logging and see if and how the Rewrite is executing:  RewriteLog logs/rewrite.log  RewriteLogLevel 9

Comment: it should work. but somehow it doesn't. anyway, let me close this ticket first. thanks.