# htaccess redirect empty uri instead of directory listing

Tags: .htaccess

If I just do `Options -Indexes`

`localhost/subdir/` would give me 500 error.
But I want to redirect it to https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema

Something like

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema [R=308,L]
```

Currently, this doesn't work on my local server.

I have to do

```
RewriteRule ^home$ https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema [R=308,L]
```

And use the url `localhost/subdir/home`

Also `Options -Indexes` seem to make the following stop working.

```
ErrorDocument 406 https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/406.html
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/406.html [R=406,L]
```

[Full original .htaccess file](https://github.com/miranda-zhang/w3id.org/blob/master/cocoon/.htaccess)

I also tried some methods in [Problem detecting empty REQUEST_URI with Apache mod_rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684940/problem-detecting-empty-request-uri-with-apache-mod-rewrite)
The following doesn't seem to work, or maybe I'm missing some other config.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/coocon
```

Or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  "^/$"
```

---

Seems something else was wrong, it is a 403 error now.

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /cocoon/ on this server.

```
Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/cocoon/: No matching
DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Comment: To affect `/subdir/` you need to place `RewriteRule ^$ https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema [R=308,L]` inside `/subdir/.htaccess`

Comment: yes, I did that. It still says 403 Forbidden

Comment: What is your full .htaccess inside `/cocoon/` ?

Comment: https://github.com/miranda-zhang/w3id.org/blob/master/cocoon/.htaccess

Comment: I didn't add it because it doesn't work on my local server yet

Comment: Add `Options +Indexes` at the top of `/cocoon/.htaccess` and retest

Comment: `Options +Indexes` gives me directory listing

Comment: Add `RewriteRule ^$ https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema [R=308,L]` just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 https://github.com/miranda-zhang/cloud-computing-schema
```